# How do I get the "edit" button (link) to appear on my profile page?

Tags: support, profile-edit

There is no "edit" button (link) on my profile page when I am logged in. I would like to correct an error and add an avatar.

How do I get the edit button to appear?

Comment: Is there no "Edit Profile & Settings" tab?

Comment: I haven't a clue. I was looking at <https://stackexchange.com/users/2341459/christopher-karl-johansen>. After stumbling around trying to find a tag that was allowed for this question, I landed on <https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/302469> (I don't know how), where I found "Edit Profile & Settings" and made changes. As to how to get back there in the future, I have no idea. Guess this question is now moot.

Comment: I see. The profile page on stackexchange.com is taken from the profile on the oldest site you have joined. If you edit that one, the one on stackexchange.com will update to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your profile page and then click on the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab:

[image]

Then you can upload an image and do all the other stuff you want to your profile.

You can get to your profile page by clicking on your image, reputation and badge count that appears at the top of every page when you are logged in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question should have been "How do I get to the page that contains this choice?"

Comment: @ChristopherKarlJohansen - That is a vital piece of information I missed out :)

Comment: thanks for that last pic.  When I go to <https://stackexchange.com/> that ribbon contains "StackExchange     1     +7          Christopher Karl Johansen     tour      about us     meta". Clicking my name takes me to <https://stackexchange.com/users/2341459/christopher-karl-johansen>.

Comment: @ChristopherKarlJohansen - ah. You don't have a profile on `stackexchange.com`. It has to be on one of the Q&A sites like Stack Overflow or DIY